# inputRichText removing alt and title attribute and showing title null after post

Tags: lightning, feeditem, null, inputrichtext

I am creating Feed Posts using a custom component in which I have used `lightning:inputRichText` But it is removing `alt` and `title` attributes from the anchor tag.
And if I am not passing the `alt` and `title` then on hover of that link the title is shown as `null`
Is there any way of resolving this?
I am really stuck on this.

***JS function -***

```
mentionUser:function(component,event) {
        var u = event.target.text;
        var id = event.target.id;
        var siteLinke = component.get("v.sitePrefix");
        var passLink = siteLinke +'/profile/' + id ;
        var link = "<a href='" + passLink +" alt='" + u +"' >@" + u + "</a>";

        var text = component.get('v.quotedMessage');
        var typeName = component.get('v.typeName');
        text = text.replace('@'+typeName, link);
        component.set("v.quotedMessage", text);

        component.set("v.oldText", text);
}
```

**quotedMessage** is the value of richtextinput.
I am passing this value to the apex Controller to save the feed.
But when I am updating the value here 
`component.set("v.quotedMessage", text);` it is not updating the replaced text with the alt and title tags. These two are removed when I set them.

Comment: can you also share the code.

Comment: Hi dinesh, can you please share your code. Or add it in a Lightning Playground and share the code.

Comment: @User6670 and Mohit Kulkarni, I have updated the code.